# How to get the index of value with list comprehension

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, rasa-nlu

I am working in Brown Corpus using NLTK. I want to separate out the `tokens` that has `tokens` tagged with `DT`

My code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown
brown_tag = brown.tagged_words()
brownDT = [(a,b) for (a,b) in brown_tag if b == 'DT']
```

The above code returns the `value` tagged with `DT` but I need the `index` too. I am trying to get the `value` and the `index` of the `value` in return. For example the output should be:

```
[index, (token, 'DT')]
```

This code does not work:

```
brownDT = [((a,b),brown_tag.index((a,b))) for (a,b) in brown_tag if b == 'DT']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
brownDT = [(i,(a,b)) for (i, (a,b)) in enumerate(brown_tag) if b == 'DT']
```